# Add comma to numbers table

Tags: r, formattable

I am having problems showing this table with numbers separated with commas as a thousand separator (i.e., from 64482 to 64,482 etc):

```
library(formattable)

df <- data.frame(id = 1:4,          
name = c("A","B","C","D"),         
usuarios = accounting(c(64482, 5077, 84428, 97869), format = "d"),         
sesiones = accounting(c(15892705, 1207458, 19521289, 25331543), format = 
"d"),          
ingresos = accounting(c(127033597, 11833290, 19979478, 268402434), format =  
"d"),      
transacciones = accounting(c(124798, 13944, 449494, 776689), format = "d"),      
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)      


align_column=c("l","l","r","r","r","r")    
formattable(df, align=align_column, list(      
area(col = c(A)) ~ normalize_bar("yellow", 0.1),      
area(col = c(B)) ~ normalize_bar("lightblue", 0.1),       
area(col = c(C)) ~ normalize_bar("silver", 0.1),       
area(col = c(D)) ~ normalize_bar("lightgreen", 0.1)))
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example is not reproducible as is. `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'A' not found`. Also, you might want to add `library(formattable)` at the start of your example!

Comment: Also, what do you mean "separated by commas"? Do you mean with comma as a thousand separator?

Comment: Thanks, I meant commas as a thousand separator.library(formattable) added to the code.

Comment: What about the `area(col = c(A))`? You don't have a column called `A`. Try to run `rm(list=ls())` (remove all list objects from the session) and then try to run your code above. That should make it easier for you to see that the code you have pasted is not error-free.

Comment: Also, can you paste the output you get from the above code, perhaps just as a picture? Because when I use `formattable(df, align=align_column)` I **do** get comma thousand separators.